# Webpage Screen Rendering Issue on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, kendo-ui

We are facing the strange issue in Chrome with rendering webpage. But, the same webpage works correctly in IE Edge or Firefox.

Added the Issue detail below which we are facing on chrome.

This is the webpage which renders correctly in the initial load.
[image]

When we hover the cursor on the chrome browser tab or chrome browser side menu, the screen flickers as below and sometimes re-renders individual elements on the webpage.

[image]

**Chrome Version** 118.0.5993.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I don’t there’s any way we can help without just guessing without seeing relevant code and preferably being able to run it. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is an enterprise app & unfortunately, i couldn't share the sample code.

Comment: Well you can check More Tools...->Developer tools for console output if any issues reported.

Comment: On the dev console there are no any issues. When we have chrome setting "Use hardware acceleration when available" this issue is reproducible. as we did some more analysis, it looks like issue with translate3d attribute in CSS which is widely used in all the kendo widgets we are using. Need help on this issue.

Comment: "transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 10px) !important" is causing this weird behavior